# How to remove double quotes from JS string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

my string is coming with duplicate `"` start and the end of string, trying to remove duplicate its printing same value.

trying to remove double quotes its not working with this code

```js
var str = ""
var item = str.includes('test');

item.replace(/\"/g, ""));
console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var someStr = 'It is "nice" to meet you';
console.log(someStr.replace(/["]+/g, ''));
```

Comment: `"It's nice to meet you"` will turn into `"Its nice to meed you"`.`'` is not a double quote.

Comment: @some fixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `string.replace` does not modify `string`, it returns the modified value, which you must then assign to a variable.

Secondly, `string.includes` returns a `boolean`, and there is no `boolean.replace`.

Try this:

```js
let str = "\"this is test string\"";
console.log(str);

str = str.replace(/\"/g, "");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only remove it if the string both starts and ends with a double quotes, and will keep double quotes if they are inside the string.

However, it is easy to fool it with a string like `'"this" will "fail"'`.

```js
function process(input) {
 return /^".*"$/.test(input) ? input.slice(1, input.length-1) : input;
};


[
'"This is a test"',
'This is a test',
'This is a "test"',
'"this" will "fail"'
].forEach( input => console.log(process(input)));
```